# Underline text in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, user-controls

I have an WPF usercontrol that has a TextBox. I set the text `Underline` or not, `Strikethrough` or not.

I think something is wrong with my code, especially *unset* part, because is not working properly every time... probably some elements of Underline are removed with Strikethrough?...

Especiallly when setting the same property multiple times to the same value, it adds and adds....

```
private void UpdateUnderline()
{
    if (this.IsUnderline)
    {
        this.MyTextBlock.TextDecorations.Add(TextDecorations.Underline);
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var item in TextDecorations.Underline)
        {
            this.MyTextBlock.TextDecorations.Remove(item);
        }
    }
}

private void UpdateStrikethrough()
{
    if (this.IsStrikethrough)
    {
        this.MyTextBlock.TextDecorations.Add(TextDecorations.Strikethrough);
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var item in TextDecorations.Strikethrough)
        {
            this.MyTextBlock.TextDecorations.Remove(item);
        }
    }
}
```

as I can't do

```
this.MyTextBlock.TextDecorations.Contains(TextDecorations.Strikethrough);
```

it adds and adds, and adds again, so when it removes...it remains :)

## Example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication10.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <CheckBox Content="Underline"
                      IsChecked="{Binding IsUnderline}" />
            <CheckBox Content="Strikethrough"
                      IsChecked="{Binding IsStrikethrough}" />
            <TextBlock Name="MyTextBlock"
                       Text="Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog." />
            <Button Content="Underline" Name="Underline" Click="Underline_Click"/>
            <Button Content="Strikethrough" Name="Strikethrough" Click="Strikethrough_Click"/>
            <Button Content="NO Underline" Name="NoUnderline" Click="NoUnderline_Click"/>
            <Button Content="NO Strikethrough" Name="NoStrikethrough" Click="NoStrikethrough_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private Boolean _IsUnderline;
    public Boolean IsUnderline
    {
        get
        {
            return _IsUnderline;
        }
        set
        {
            _IsUnderline = value;
            UpdateUnderline();
        }
    }
    private Boolean _IsStrikethrough;
    public Boolean IsStrikethrough
    {
        get
        {
            return _IsStrikethrough;
        }
        set
        {
            _IsStrikethrough = value;
            UpdateStrikethrough();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateUnderline()
    {
        if (this.IsUnderline)
        {
            this.MyTextBlock.TextDecorations.Add(TextDecorations.Underline);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var item in TextDecorations.Underline)
            {
                this.MyTextBlock.TextDecorations.Remove(item);
            }
        }
    }

    private void UpdateStrikethrough()
    {
        if (this.IsStrikethrough)
        {
            this.MyTextBlock.TextDecorations.Add(TextDecorations.Strikethrough);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var item in TextDecorations.Strikethrough)
            {
                this.MyTextBlock.TextDecorations.Remove(item);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Underline_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsUnderline = true;
    }

    private void Strikethrough_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsStrikethrough = true;
    }

    private void NoUnderline_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsUnderline = false;
    }

    private void NoStrikethrough_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsStrikethrough = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing a for each on the non-true block of your if statements?

Comment: @Nate: because this is the life :) ... I don't know otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"dirty" solution:

```
    private void UpdateUnderline()
    {
        if (this.IsUnderline)
        {
            foreach (var item in TextDecorations.Underline)
            {
                this.MyTextBlock.TextDecorations.Remove(item);
            }
            this.MyTextBlock.TextDecorations.Add(TextDecorations.Underline);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var item in TextDecorations.Underline)
            {
                this.MyTextBlock.TextDecorations.Remove(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recreated it and works fine:

### Recreation:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <CheckBox Content="Underline"
                      IsChecked="{Binding IsUnderline}" />
            <CheckBox Content="Strikethrough"
                      IsChecked="{Binding IsStrikethrough}" />
            <TextBlock Name="MyTextBlock"
                       Text="Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog." />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private Boolean _IsUnderline;
    public Boolean IsUnderline
    {
        get
        {
            return _IsUnderline;
        }
        set
        {
            _IsUnderline = value;
            UpdateUnderline();
        }
    }
    private Boolean _IsStrikethrough;
    public Boolean IsStrikethrough
    {
        get
        {
            return _IsStrikethrough;
        }
        set
        {
            _IsStrikethrough = value;
            UpdateStrikethrough();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateUnderline()
    {
        if (this.IsUnderline)
        {
            this.MyTextBlock.TextDecorations.Add(TextDecorations.Underline);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var item in TextDecorations.Underline)
            {
                this.MyTextBlock.TextDecorations.Remove(item);
            }
        }
    }

    private void UpdateStrikethrough()
    {
        if (this.IsStrikethrough)
        {
            this.MyTextBlock.TextDecorations.Add(TextDecorations.Strikethrough);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var item in TextDecorations.Strikethrough)
            {
                this.MyTextBlock.TextDecorations.Remove(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```